# How to Handle Popup Windows That Occur within Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

So I have an issue where, I am trying to automate an Import on an application that has no API. 
As a result, I have to do like 30 navigation clicks just to get to what I want (Exaggeration).
However, I am trying to basically automate the clicks that will allow me to upload a specific file. 
As a result, I almost get to the part where I have to select the specific test build I want to import the file with. There is a field that I need to do a `send_keys` to find the correct import build I have to upload. The Field element looks like this

```
<input class="lookupInput" type="text" name="brTestScoreImportLookupInput" id="brTestScoreImportLookupInput" style="width: 100px;" tabindex="1" onkeydown="return lookupKeyPressed(event,&quot;&quot;,&quot;simptbrws000.w&quot;)" origvalue="" det="true" aria-labelledby="" autocomplete="off">
```

However I don't think my code is properly handling the window as it pops-up from the prior selection. 
The field I need to update can be found in the picture I uploaded:
[image]
Furthermore the XPATH for the Field is `//*[@id='brTestScoreImportLookupInput']`
You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Skyward/skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py).
The main aspect is I have to Enter `TSI` into that `File ID` field and then hit `enter` on my keyboard to populate the correct import utility I need. Once I do that the import utilities filter out and I need to select a specific `File ID`: 
[image].

The main code that should be controlling this:

```
# Click on Test Score Import Wizard - TW
# Test Wizard XPATH = //a[@id='tree1-3-link']/span
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='tree1-3-link']/span")))
element.click();

# Send test_upload and Send Keys
# Field XPATH = //*[@id='brTestScoreImportLookupInput']
test_lookup = browser.find_element_by_id("brTestScoreImportLookupInput")
test_lookup.send_keys(test_upload)
```

If you want to visit the link toe repository code click on here above this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File ".\skyward_collegeboard_TSI_import.py", line 115, in
    <module> test_lookup = browser.find_element_by_id("brTestScoreImportLookupInput") File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_) File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
      line 976, in find_element return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, { File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
      line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="brTestScoreImportLookupInput"]"}
      (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
```

Comment: >"However I don't think my code is properly handling the window as it pops-up"
 What happens when you run the code though? Nothing/errors?

Comment: No I get errors. Let me paste it here

Comment: No I get errors I will add it to the Question

Comment: @0buz I have added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Is the element inside an `iframe` by any chance? Would be good if you could post the html source. But if your element is indeed in an iframe you need to switch first to the iframe before finding the field. Do that with `driver.switch_to.frame(>>iframe name or id here)`

Comment: I don't believe it is, what happens is I hit a link and then a new window will pop up. For example if I click on this element ```<a class="link-active" onclick="tree1.setActive('tree1-3');this.blur();" id="tree1-3-link" href="javascript:gUseMenuId='11680'; openNewWindow('simptbrws000.w',1000,700,0,'');" aria-labelledby="" style=""><div class="icon_doc">&nbsp;</div><span>Test Score Import Wizard - TW</span></a>``` then it will open up to that window.

Comment: After I click on that element I need to update the element field in the window that popped up ```<input class="lookupInput" type="text" name="brTestScoreImportLookupInput" id="brTestScoreImportLookupInput" style="width: 100px;" tabindex="1" onkeydown="return lookupKeyPressed(event,&quot;&quot;,&quot;simptbrws000.w&quot;)" origvalue="" det="true" aria-labelledby="" autocomplete="off">``` @0buz does that help?

Comment: So I was able to send the keys but I don't know how to use enter on the keyboard I presume with the OS module

Comment: `.send_keys("ENTER")`.

Comment: Ah thank you, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to accomplish this by using the following method using both selenium and pynput.

```
# Browser Switches to Window
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])

# Send test_upload and oend Keys
# Field XPATH = //*[@id='brTestScoreImportLookupInput']
test_lookup = browser.find_element_by_id("brTestScoreImportLookupInput")
test_lookup.send_keys(test_upload)

# Press and Release Enter Key
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Essentially I had to switch to that popup window.